# Matlab: 10 fold cross giving same fold over and over

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, cell

I have attached the data at the bottom of the question: I have following code that return the 10 fold in a cell, such a way that cell{1,1} consider the training data and cell{1,2} test data but for some reason beyond cell{1,1} which cell{1,2}.... has same data repeating over and over. I am not really sure why its happening. I debug so many rounds and was not able to figure the reason.

Here is the code,

```
%Function that accept data file as a name and the number of folds
%For the cross fold
function [results_cell] = GetTenFold(dataFile, x)
%loading the data file
dataMatrix = load(dataFile);
%combine the data and labels as one matrix
X = [dataMatrix.data dataMatrix.labels];
%geting the length of the of matrix
dataRowNumber = length(dataMatrix.data);
%shuffle the matrix while keeping rows intact 
shuffledMatrix = X(randperm(size(X,1)),:);
crossValidationFolds = x;
%Assinging number of rows per fold
numberOfRowsPerFold = dataRowNumber / crossValidationFolds;
%Assigning 10X2 cell to hold each fold as training and test data
results_cell = cell(10,2);
    %starting from the first row and segment it based on folds
    i = 1;
    for startOfRow = 1:numberOfRowsPerFold:dataRowNumber
        testRows = startOfRow:startOfRow+numberOfRowsPerFold-1;
        if (startOfRow == 1)
            trainRows = (max(testRows)+1:dataRowNumber);
        else
            trainRows = [1:startOfRow-1 max(testRows)+1:dataRowNumber];
            i = i + 1;
        end
        %for i=1:10
        results_cell{i,1} = shuffledMatrix(trainRows ,:);
        results_cell{i,2} = shuffledMatrix(testRows ,:);
    end
end
data

5.1000    3.5000    1.4000    0.2000
4.9000    3.0000    1.4000    0.2000
4.7000    3.2000    1.3000    0.2000
4.6000    3.1000    1.5000    0.2000
5.0000    3.6000    1.4000    0.2000
5.4000    3.9000    1.7000    0.4000
4.6000    3.4000    1.4000    0.3000
5.0000    3.4000    1.5000    0.2000
4.4000    2.9000    1.4000    0.2000
4.9000    3.1000    1.5000    0.1000
5.4000    3.7000    1.5000    0.2000
4.8000    3.4000    1.6000    0.2000
4.8000    3.0000    1.4000    0.1000
4.3000    3.0000    1.1000    0.1000
5.8000    4.0000    1.2000    0.2000
5.7000    4.4000    1.5000    0.4000
5.4000    3.9000    1.3000    0.4000
5.1000    3.5000    1.4000    0.3000
5.7000    3.8000    1.7000    0.3000
5.1000    3.8000    1.5000    0.3000
5.4000    3.4000    1.7000    0.2000
5.1000    3.7000    1.5000    0.4000
4.6000    3.6000    1.0000    0.2000
5.1000    3.3000    1.7000    0.5000
4.8000    3.4000    1.9000    0.2000
5.0000    3.0000    1.6000    0.2000
5.0000    3.4000    1.6000    0.4000
5.2000    3.5000    1.5000    0.2000
5.2000    3.4000    1.4000    0.2000
4.7000    3.2000    1.6000    0.2000
4.8000    3.1000    1.6000    0.2000
5.4000    3.4000    1.5000    0.4000
5.2000    4.1000    1.5000    0.1000
5.5000    4.2000    1.4000    0.2000
4.9000    3.1000    1.5000    0.1000
5.0000    3.2000    1.2000    0.2000
5.5000    3.5000    1.3000    0.2000
4.9000    3.1000    1.5000    0.1000
4.4000    3.0000    1.3000    0.2000
5.1000    3.4000    1.5000    0.2000
5.0000    3.5000    1.3000    0.3000
4.5000    2.3000    1.3000    0.3000
4.4000    3.2000    1.3000    0.2000
5.0000    3.5000    1.6000    0.6000
5.1000    3.8000    1.9000    0.4000
4.8000    3.0000    1.4000    0.3000
5.1000    3.8000    1.6000    0.2000
4.6000    3.2000    1.4000    0.2000
5.3000    3.7000    1.5000    0.2000
5.0000    3.3000    1.4000    0.2000
7.0000    3.2000    4.7000    1.4000
6.4000    3.2000    4.5000    1.5000
6.9000    3.1000    4.9000    1.5000
5.5000    2.3000    4.0000    1.3000
6.5000    2.8000    4.6000    1.5000
5.7000    2.8000    4.5000    1.3000
6.3000    3.3000    4.7000    1.6000
4.9000    2.4000    3.3000    1.0000
6.6000    2.9000    4.6000    1.3000
5.2000    2.7000    3.9000    1.4000
5.0000    2.0000    3.5000    1.0000
5.9000    3.0000    4.2000    1.5000
6.0000    2.2000    4.0000    1.0000
6.1000    2.9000    4.7000    1.4000
5.6000    2.9000    3.6000    1.3000
6.7000    3.1000    4.4000    1.4000
5.6000    3.0000    4.5000    1.5000
5.8000    2.7000    4.1000    1.0000
6.2000    2.2000    4.5000    1.5000
5.6000    2.5000    3.9000    1.1000
5.9000    3.2000    4.8000    1.8000
6.1000    2.8000    4.0000    1.3000
6.3000    2.5000    4.9000    1.5000
6.1000    2.8000    4.7000    1.2000
6.4000    2.9000    4.3000    1.3000
6.6000    3.0000    4.4000    1.4000
6.8000    2.8000    4.8000    1.4000
6.7000    3.0000    5.0000    1.7000
6.0000    2.9000    4.5000    1.5000
5.7000    2.6000    3.5000    1.0000
5.5000    2.4000    3.8000    1.1000
5.5000    2.4000    3.7000    1.0000
5.8000    2.7000    3.9000    1.2000
6.0000    2.7000    5.1000    1.6000
5.4000    3.0000    4.5000    1.5000
6.0000    3.4000    4.5000    1.6000
6.7000    3.1000    4.7000    1.5000
6.3000    2.3000    4.4000    1.3000
5.6000    3.0000    4.1000    1.3000
5.5000    2.5000    4.0000    1.3000
5.5000    2.6000    4.4000    1.2000
6.1000    3.0000    4.6000    1.4000
5.8000    2.6000    4.0000    1.2000
5.0000    2.3000    3.3000    1.0000
5.6000    2.7000    4.2000    1.3000
5.7000    3.0000    4.2000    1.2000
5.7000    2.9000    4.2000    1.3000
6.2000    2.9000    4.3000    1.3000
5.1000    2.5000    3.0000    1.1000
5.7000    2.8000    4.1000    1.3000
6.3000    3.3000    6.0000    2.5000
5.8000    2.7000    5.1000    1.9000
7.1000    3.0000    5.9000    2.1000
6.3000    2.9000    5.6000    1.8000
6.5000    3.0000    5.8000    2.2000
7.6000    3.0000    6.6000    2.1000
4.9000    2.5000    4.5000    1.7000
7.3000    2.9000    6.3000    1.8000
6.7000    2.5000    5.8000    1.8000
7.2000    3.6000    6.1000    2.5000
6.5000    3.2000    5.1000    2.0000
6.4000    2.7000    5.3000    1.9000
6.8000    3.0000    5.5000    2.1000
5.7000    2.5000    5.0000    2.0000
5.8000    2.8000    5.1000    2.4000
6.4000    3.2000    5.3000    2.3000
6.5000    3.0000    5.5000    1.8000
7.7000    3.8000    6.7000    2.2000
7.7000    2.6000    6.9000    2.3000
6.0000    2.2000    5.0000    1.5000
6.9000    3.2000    5.7000    2.3000
5.6000    2.8000    4.9000    2.0000
7.7000    2.8000    6.7000    2.0000
6.3000    2.7000    4.9000    1.8000
6.7000    3.3000    5.7000    2.1000
7.2000    3.2000    6.0000    1.8000
6.2000    2.8000    4.8000    1.8000
6.1000    3.0000    4.9000    1.8000
6.4000    2.8000    5.6000    2.1000
7.2000    3.0000    5.8000    1.6000
7.4000    2.8000    6.1000    1.9000
7.9000    3.8000    6.4000    2.0000
6.4000    2.8000    5.6000    2.2000
6.3000    2.8000    5.1000    1.5000
6.1000    2.6000    5.6000    1.4000
7.7000    3.0000    6.1000    2.3000
6.3000    3.4000    5.6000    2.4000
6.4000    3.1000    5.5000    1.8000
6.0000    3.0000    4.8000    1.8000
6.9000    3.1000    5.4000    2.1000
6.7000    3.1000    5.6000    2.4000
6.9000    3.1000    5.1000    2.3000
5.8000    2.7000    5.1000    1.9000
6.8000    3.2000    5.9000    2.3000
6.7000    3.3000    5.7000    2.5000
6.7000    3.0000    5.2000    2.3000
6.3000    2.5000    5.0000    1.9000
6.5000    3.0000    5.2000    2.0000
6.2000    3.4000    5.4000    2.3000
5.9000    3.0000    5.1000    1.8000
```

labels =

```
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
```

Comment: I suggest that you do the debugging and identify the actual statement that does not behave as it should or as you would expect it to. Then ask the question.

Comment: can you clarify "beyond cell{1,1} which cell{1,2}.... has same data repeating over and over."? Your code works for me, in making non-overlapping and train/test sets and distinct partitions for the different folds.